# What are the benefits of using Parse Local Datastore over CoreData in iOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, parse-platform

I am a new developer currently I am building an iOS app with a parse backend.

I need a cloud -based database so I can add new content to the app, but need to persist the user data so that even if they delete the app they can restore from their data.

Could someone please explain if Datastore is a good replacement for CoreData?

Comment: If all of the data you intend to persist on the client is also data kept in parse.com, then I think the parse solution is superior, saving you some trouble in synchronizing the local copy.  This is an important question, but I'm going to vote to close, since on SO, I think it requires too much of an opinionated response.

Comment: Are you referring to core data syncing to iCloud vs parse server datastore??

Comment: @jkr - the op asks about core data, the iOS framework abstracting a local sqlite database.

Comment: @danh, he can save users data in coreData, and sync it to iCloud. Even if user deletes the app, the data still resides in iCloud and can get the data back to device. He might be asking this solution vs parse server datastore.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to use the local datastore provided by Parse if you want to cache your PFObjects.

Because:

- You can save the same objects into the local datastore as you use online
- The performance is really good because you don't need to fill up your core data objects from your PFObjects (cannot cast from PFObject to a Core Data Object).
- The code is clearer (consistent)